# How to select resistor with specific package size

Tags: eaglecad

I have some SMD resistors in size 1812. How do I select this package size in the part library? I see all the other sizes, 2010, 1210, 1206, etc, but no 1812. I'm new to Eagle, and the interface is a bit confusing to me but searching 1812 produces nothing. Searching for "resistor" produces a lot, but there's a ton of nested results that are tedious to scroll through.

What's the proper way to find a specific part in a specific package size?

Answer (score 3):

The "proper way" is to make the footprint yourself. That way, you can be sure the footprint is correct (and, when it comes time to make a more complex footprint, you will already be familiar with the process).

If that sounds unpleasant, you can simply Google "1812 resistor eagle" and hope the person who made whichever one you find knew what they were doing, but understand that making your own footprints is typically a necessity of board design (unless you work in a company that has engineers specifically for that sort of thing).

Comment: I agree with this - when I was starting out and I thought that the manufactureres would always provide the footprints, I struggled. But as soon as I figured out how to do it myself, it really boosted what I could do in CAD.

Comment: Yes, I know people can create their own parts, and I'm posting here because Google came up empty. I'm just a little bewildered that I need to create a custom part for a *resistor* in a *industry standard package* size. Folks here hate Fritzing, but even that has this package footprint in its standard library. Does Eagle not include most industry standard footprints? I'm giving Eagle a try because everyone here raves about it, but if it's going to have a steep learning curve and require me to create every footprint manually, that's going to be a massive expense I can't afford.

Comment: @Cerin I'll be honest with you, IMO Fritzing and Eagle are both rubbish. I would recommend you use [KiCad](https://kicad.org/), which is _free_ and quite capable. I'm not going to claim it's superior to Eagle in every way, but for me, it's much better in just about every respect, and significantly more friendly to DIY/open-source. Also, as a cherry on top, it just so happens to have an 1812 resistor footprint in the included libraries :) [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @uint128_t, Interesting. Thanks for the input. I'd toyed around with KiCad, but never got into it because there didn't seem to be as much documentation or community as either Fritzing or Eagle, but I'll give it another look.